# Exception when creating a GenericObjectPool using lettuce-mod

Tags: redis, lettuce

Lettuce-mod 3.6.0 and commons-pool2 2.11.1
We are creating the redis client:

```
this.client = RedisModulesClient.create(redisURI);
```

And right after the pool as it's shown in the github lettucemod page:

```
GenericObjectPoolConfig<StatefulRedisModulesConnection<String, String>> config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig<>();
config.setMaxTotal(20);
this.pool = ConnectionPoolSupport.createGenericObjectPool(() -> this.client.connect(), config);
```

Since we didn't see this working, we printed the 'this.pool' variable right after to be created, and the info we see is:

```
this.pool =  [maxTotal=20, blockWhenExhausted=true, maxWaitDuration=PT-0.001S, lifo=true, fairness=false, testOnCreate=false, testOnBorrow=false, testOnReturn=false, testWhileIdle=false, durationBetweenEvictionRuns=PT-0.001S, numTestsPerEvictionRun=3, minEvictableIdleTimeDuration=PT30M, softMinEvictableIdleTimeDuration=PT-0.001S, evictionPolicy=org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultEvictionPolicy@cf649db, closeLock=java.lang.Object@cf79f21, closed=false, evictionLock=java.lang.Object@cf79f23, evictor=null, evictionIterator=null, factoryClassLoader=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@cf64a1b, oname=org.apache.commons.pool2:type=GenericObjectPool,name=pool6, creationStackTrace=java.lang.Exception
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool.<init>(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:407)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.<init>(GenericObjectPool.java:147)
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$1.<init>(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:117)
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport.createGenericObjectPool(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:117)
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport.createGenericObjectPool(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:94)
    at com.ventusproxy.proxy.cluster.storages.RedisClusterImpl.createPool(RedisClusterImpl.java:155)
    at com.ventusproxy.proxy.cluster.storages.RedisClusterImpl.startup(RedisClusterImpl.java:99)
    at com.ventusproxy.proxy.cluster.storages.RedisClusterImpl.start(RedisClusterImpl.java:44)
    at com.ventusproxy.proxy.services.storage.StorageService.addStorage(StorageService.java:50)
    at com.ventusproxy.proxy.services.storage.StorageService.startup(StorageService.java:35)
    at com.ventusproxy.proxy.servlet.data.GlobalData.startPrimaryServices(GlobalData.java:279)
    at com.ventusproxy.proxy.servlet.data.GlobalData.startVentus(GlobalData.java:175)
    at com.ventusproxy.proxy.servlet.data.GlobalData.start(GlobalData.java:108)
    at com.ventusproxy.proxy.servlet.AsyncProxyServlet.init(AsyncProxyServlet.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1011)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5267)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:887)
, borrowedCount=0, returnedCount=0, createdCount=0, destroyedCount=0, destroyedByEvictorCount=0, destroyedByBorrowValidationCount=0, activeTimes=StatsStore [[]], size=100, index=0], idleTimes=StatsStore [[]], size=100, index=0], waitTimes=StatsStore [[]], size=100, index=0], maxBorrowWaitDuration=PT0S, swallowedExceptionListener=null, factoryType=null, maxIdle=10, minIdle=5, factory=RedisPooledObjectFactory [], allObjects={}, createCount=0, idleObjects=[], abandonedConfig=null]
```

Since there is no more information, we have no idea about what's going on. We tried different commons-pool2 versions with the same result.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please, forget this and sorry ...

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I am observing similar error with JedisPooled and doubting if connections are actually getting pooled.